# Mongoose case insensitive schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to make all find calls inside a schema be case insensitive. This is what I got so far:

```
const user = new new mongoose.Schema({
        username: {
            trim: true,
            required: true,
            type: String,
            match : [
                new RegExp('^[a-z0-9_.-]+$', 'i'),
                '{PATH} \'{VALUE}\' invalid'
            ],
            validate : [
                (username, callback) => {
                    console.log(username);

                    user.findOne({ username: new RegExp(`/^${username}$/i`) }, (err, doc) => {
                        if(!doc) return callback(false);
                        return callback(true);
                    });
                },
                'Username already exists'
            ]
        });
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this working through a middleware:

```
user.pre('find', function() {
    if (this._conditions.username) {
        this._conditions.username = new RegExp(this._conditions.username.replace(/\./g, '\\\\.'), 'i');
    }
});
```

Comment: If the username contains `.` it allows anything to match that character.

Comment: Uhmm, I see, is there any solution to overcome this?

Comment: No I mean if you construct a `RegExp` from the username, and the username contains a `.`, it will allow any character except newlines to match.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that.

Comment: If usernames only contain `^[a-z0-9_.-]+`, all you need to do to fix it is pass `username.replace(/\./g, '\\\\.')` instead of the `username` itself.

Answer (score 4):

You can make your schema insensitive by defining what mongoDb calls a collation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-case-insensitive/ when creating a new instance of a mongoose.Schema.

```
var someSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   username: {type: String, required: true}
}, {
   collation: { locale: 'en', strength: 2 }
});
```

Now you have applied case-insenstitive logic on the schema level which will be reflected and used when querying the model of this schema.

```
someModel.findOne({username: 'UsERName1'})
```

The above query would now be made case-insensitive due to your collation on the models corresponding schema.

Comment: straight to the point! , thanks man

Comment: Remember that you'll need to recreate your collection to apply the collation if the collection already exists. As of MongoDB 3.4, you can't change the collation of an existing collection. You'd have to create a new collection with the collation you want, and then migrate the documents to the new collection.